# Для чего в наследовании надо переопределять constructor

Tags: javascript, ооп

Наследование в javascript реализуется так

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)
Child.prototype.constructor = Child
```

Вопрос в следующем: зачем нужна 2-ая строка?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дело в том, что когда создается функция, интерпретаторы javascript автоматически назначают ей свойство prototype:

```
function Foo() {
    // ...
}
Foo.prototype = { constructor: Foo }; // Происходит неявно и автоматически
```

Так исторически сложилось. А раз такое свойство есть - то есть и библиотеки которые на него завязываются!

Поэтому при переопределении свойства prototype нужно восстановить правильное значение constructor.

Comment: Спасибо
А можно хотя бы 1 или 2 примера этих библиотек?